# Dynamic JSON property names in WebForms web application possible?

Tags: javascript, json, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I converted an old .NET 3.5 WebForms "Website" into a "Web application". Now i don't know, if that is the cause, but all the dynamic JSON property names, that were working before are now producing syntax errors ("Property name expected") in the aspx pages eq.

```
...
rules: {
    <%= txtDisabledFromDate.UniqueID %>: {
        required: function(element) {
            return jQuery("#<%= rbDisabledBetween.ClientID %>:checked").size() == 1; 
        },
        digits: true
    },
...
```

If i surround the `<%= txtDisabledFromDate.UniqueID %>` with double quotes the errors go away, but then the javascript stops working.

Comment: I can help you, chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24042/saj

Comment: Can you show the resulting JSON string (with or w/o "s). Is not that `<%= txtDisabledFromDate.UniqueID %>` evaluates to a property name with a space as the first character? (And it wouldn't like this `<%=txtDisabledFromDate.UniqueID %>`)

Comment: See what is UniqueID. It may start with a number and if so, it will produce an error.

Comment: @FAngel: you mean when it's a combination of numbers and letters, starting with a number?

Comment: Yes. If it is not like that, just show a value of `txtDisabledFromDate.UniqueID` which produce an error. Possibly there is something else that cause a problem. But if you wrap it with `"` and it works, than I see no problem here at all. Validation plugin (I guess that is a rule for it?) should handle that correctly